# Add price range with jQuery and php

Tags: php, jquery

I want to add jQuery price range but when I add it, it is always blank. I made sure to include all classes, I tried tutorials and still did not show up.

Here is one of the tutorials that I tried [link](https://phppot.com/php/php-price-range-search-using-jquery-slider/)

It looks like this when I out the codes into my page

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSr4k.png)

Here are my classes:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"
       href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Slider code

```
 <div class="form-price-range-filter">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div>
            <input type="" id="min" name="min_price"
                value="<?php echo $min; ?>">
            <div id="slider-range"></div>
            <input type="" id="max" name="max_price"
                value="<?php echo $max; ?>">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_range"
                value="Filter Product" class="btn-submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 1000,
      values: [ <?php echo $min; ?>, <?php echo $max; ?> ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).html( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        $( "#min" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
        $( "#max" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
      }
      });
    $( "#amount" ).html( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
     " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
  </script>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? I tried at least 10 tutorials before posting here - all have the same result with me

Comment: Have you checked what the PHP is outputting in to the HTML/JS? That's most likely where any issues will lie. Also check the console for errors. If you need debugging help then we would need to see the actual HTML output, with the PHP removed as it's not entirely relevant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the only thing in my console is this ::::
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap::::: also i tried with row html and still did not work

Comment: If you hard-code the min and max values then it seems to work. Nothing is "blank", as you describe. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/buyog6nf/ . Like Rory said, have you checked what is being output by PHP? You can use the View Source feature of your page to see what the finished Javascript and HTML actually looks like once PHP has put the output of $min and $max into it. Since we can't see your PHP code, or any data which lies behind it, we can't directly help you with fixing that right now.